# Implementing Tiny Encryption Algorithm on OS X

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

I'm working through the exercises in Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++".  In Chapter 25 he introduces the Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA).  He and the web site that host a few papers on it claim that it hasn't been broken, and given how short the code is that seems "Too good to be true!"

Note I had to change the `long` variables to `int` variables because the bit shifts are designed to be implemented on a system with `sizeof(var) = 4`

OS X implements long as an 8 byte type, so without this change Stroustrup's code doesn't work.

Can anyone recommend other trivially implemented improvements to get TEA running on OS X with more efficiency and/or better security?

```
void encipher(
    const unsigned int* const v,
    unsigned int* const w,
    const unsigned int* const k
    )
{
    unsigned int y = v[0];
    unsigned int z = v[1];
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    unsigned int delta = 0x9E3779B9;
    unsigned int n = 32;

    while(n-- > 0) {
        y += (z << 4 ^ z >> 5) + z ^ sum + k[sum & 3];
        sum += delta;
        z += (y << 4 ^ y >> 5) + y ^ sum + k[sum>>11 & 3];
    }
    w[0]=y;
    w[1]=z;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look _trivially_ breakable, but there is a _lot_ of analysis going to an algorithm before it can be deemed in any way secure. There is very little reason to not use something more well analysed if you need secure encryption.

Comment: Do the weaknesses listed on [The Wikipedia for TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) give you any indication whether you should be using it given the security parameters you require (and we don't know) ? And if you to ensure 32-bit values, use `uint32_t` (though not *manadated* by the standard, i've yet to see an implementation that doesn't provide it in `<stdint.h>`)

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm using TEA to learn about it.  No real application domain at this point.  Also for the sake of learning can you explain the benefit of using uint32_t?  Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @user3176017 if provided by the implementation in `stdint.h` (or `cstdint` for C++) it is defined to be whatever type is needed to accommodate a 32-bit unsigned integer type. The algorithm requires that (32bit unsigned) and the change you made somewhat back-doors it but still in an implementation-dependent fashion. The implementation provided on Wiki uses `uint32_t` precisely for this reason, and I would suggest you use it as your template.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm#Properties) (come on, man, google!)

> TEA has a few weaknesses. Most notably, it suffers from equivalent keys—each key is equivalent to three others, which means that the effective key size is only 126 bits. As a result, TEA is especially bad as a cryptographic hash function. This weakness led to a method for hacking Microsoft's Xbox game console, where the cipher was used as a hash function. TEA is also susceptible to a related-key attack which requires 2^23 chosen plaintexts under a related-key pair, with 2^32 time complexity. Because of these weaknesses, the XTEA cipher was designed.

Comment: Soren, I did Google...and read the wikipedia.  I added the question because of the edits required to get it to work on OS X versus the code provided by Stroustrup in his book.

Comment: Sorry, I may have read your comment too quickly. The Wikipedia XTEA implementation is quite precise about bit width where it matters, so I shouldn't expect you to encounter any problems on Mac OS.